# What is proper letter ending greeting for a letter to a teacher?

Tags: politeness, formality, chinese

In Chinese letter writing there is a phrase "教祺" that can be roughly translated as "good luck in teaching" and is used exclusively in the letter ending greeting. Is there a counterpart in Japanese letter writing? Or is wishing the teacher's health good enough?

Edit: found a [rather long list](http://www.iwate-jh.ed.jp/pfc/pfc01.htm) of letter greetings and cannot find anything specific to teachers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard formal opening, equivalent to English "Dear Sir/Madam", is 拝啓. The closing, equivalent to "Sincerely Yours", is 敬具. I don't see why you couldn't put in the Chinese greeting as well, along with a little explanation. The teacher might find it interesting/charming, and there's nothing wrong with a little cross-cultural exchange.